# Theory behind transfer function transforms of the type $H(s) \rightarrow H(f(s))$

Tags: filter-design, lowpass-filter, transfer-function

My brother wanted me to derive a high-pass version of a Butterworth low-pass filter. I found that the transform $H \left( s \right) \rightarrow H \left( j - j s \right)$ does the thing, but I can't really explain why. There's a scaling going on so you would probably do well to multiply the argument by something like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Basically, this is a rotation followed by a translation in the vector space. Or a translation followed by a rotation. It's kind of commutative but not really. I think this operation has a period of $4$, kind of like the Fourier Transform, or just a simple rotation by multiplying with the imaginary unit. This is ignoring the scaling factor and I haven't proven this.

My question: if there is a theory on transforms on rational functions in the $s$-plane, and where can I read all about it?

Matlab has `lp2hp()` which works on the coefficients of the discrete version of the filter as far as I know.

Comment: My code that does the transformation is here: https://pastebin.com/QPEfADJY

Answer (score 1):

These frequency transformations converting a prototype lowpass filter to a different lowpass filter or to other filter types are treated in most classic texts on filters, e.g., [1]. Many texts on digital filters also discuss such transformations of analog filters because these analog filters are then used as prototypes for designing digital filters by the bilinear transformation. Some information on frequency transformations can also be found [here](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/Microwave_and_RF_Design_IV%3A_Modules_(Steer)/02%3A_Filters/2.09%3A_Filter_Transformations).

The standard way to transform a lowpass filter to a highpass filter is simply by inverting the complex variable $s$:
$$s\rightarrow\frac{1}{s}$$
The lowpass cut-off frequency $\omega_c$ is mapped to the highpass cut-off $1/\omega_c$.

The transformation of a lowpass filter to a bandpass filter is

$$s\rightarrow \frac{s^2+\omega_0^2}{s}$$

where $\omega_0$ is the center frequency of the bandpass filter.

Finally, the transformation for obtaining a bandstop filter from a lowpass is

$$s\rightarrow \frac{s}{s^2+\omega_0^2}$$

Note that the transformations to bandpass and bandstop filters double the filter order.

You can find more details on these transformation in Section 7.2.10 of [1].

---

EDIT: The transformation $s\rightarrow j(1-s)$ proposed in the question doesn't work. First of all, the resulting filter isn't real-valued, i.e., it can't be implemented with a single filter, and second, the resulting response is generally no highpass if the prototype is a lowpass filter. Take as an example the first-order lowpass response

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{1+s}$$

The suggested transformation results in

$$H(j(1-s))=\frac{1}{1+j(1-s)}$$

which corresponds to a complex-valued filter, and which has a lowpass characteristic instead of the desired highpass characteristic.

---

[1] Parks, Burrus, *Digital Filter Design*, 1987.

Comment: I knew about s -> s^-1. The same transformation works for discrete filters, ie. z -> z^-1. I suppose s -> j - js does something similar to values of s on the line -oo j to +oo j

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm: That transformation doesn't work. See my edited answer.

Comment: I believe you made a typo: "Finally, the transformation for obtaining a bandpass filter from a lowpass filter is" -- band*stop* makes sense in that instance.

Comment: @TimWescott: Sure, that was a typo, thanks! Corrected.

Comment: I think the arrows should be pointing in the opposite direction.